# Module pattern javascript not a function?

Tags: javascript, module-pattern

I am trying to make my javascript code adherent to a Module pattern which I am following here:

http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript

This is my code currently, there are no syntax issues apart from the runtime call which says

> loosetime.init() is not a function.

```
var loosetime = (function () {
    var looseconfig = {
        "format": "DD/MM/YY HH24:MM:SS.s",
        "value": "DD/MM/YY 00:00.00",
        "class": "input",
        "delims": ['/', '-', '_', '.', '|', ',', ' ', ':']
    };

    function loosetime(a, b, c, d, e) {
        var format = a;
        var appendLoc = b;
        var inputVal = c;
        var inputName = d;
        var inputClass = e;
        var inputLength;

        try {
            if (typeof(format) == 'undefined') {
                format = looseconfig.format;
            } else {
                format = parseDateTime(format);
            }

            try {
                if (typeof(inputVal) == 'undefined') {
                    inputVal = looseconfig.value;
                }

                inputLength = inputVal.length - 2;
                var input = document.createElement("input");
                input.setAttribute("name", inputName);
                input.setAttribute("maxlength", inputLength);
                input.setAttribute("size", inputLength);
                input.setAttribute("value", inputVal);
                input.setAttribute("type", "input");
                input.setAttribute("class", inputClass);
                input.setAttribute("onkeypress", "dateTimeRules(event)");
                input.setAttribute("onclick", "resetCursorPos(event)");
                input.setAttribute("loosetime", format);

                try {
                    var element = document.getElementById(appendLoc);

                    element.appendChild(input);
                } catch (e) {
                    window.alert("Error, no Element given to append loosetime to.")
                }
            } catch (e) {
                window.alert("Error, Value is invalid." + e.toString());
            }
        } catch (e) {
            window.alert("Error, Date format missing or invalid.");
        }
    }

    // other code here ...

    return {
        init: loosetime()
    }

    // end private closure then run the closure
    });
```

Ideally I just want loosetime to work, I don't want to explicitly call the constructor.

e.g. loosetime("foo", "bar", "etc", "yolo", "123321");

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, do I need to return the function itself rather than an alias?

Comment: Not sure why I am getting downvoted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two things wrong.

First you need to make sure your module is a self invoking anonymous function (SIAF), a.k.a immediately invoked function expression (IIFE).
You can find more info on this topic [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE).

Second you can't invoke the `loosetime` function inside your module because it doesn't return anything. You need the value of the `init` key to be a reference to the `loosetime` function.

```
var loosetime = (function () {

  // ...

  function loosetime(a, b, c, d, e) {
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  return {
    init: loosetime // Note that init has a reference to loosetime and we don't execute it.
  };

})(); // Note that you're missing the execution parentheses.
```

Now you can call `init` and the `loosetime` function inside your module will be executed.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> return {
>     init: loosetime()
> }
> ```

`init` is the **return value** of *calling* `loosetime` (which is `undefined` since that function doesn't have a `return` statement).

Remove the `()` if you want to assign the function itself instead of calling it.

---

Your second problem is that the revealing module pattern requires that you *run the closure*:

```
//end private closure then run the closure
})();
```

Despite your comment, you missed off the `()` there.

Comment: I already have that, please look at the source code at the bottom

Comment: @kaleeway — The code I quoted is taken from your question, so of course you have it. That code is the problem. Read the rest of the answer to see how to fix it.

Comment: Thanks, your solution is still giving the result loosetime.init() is not a function.